# how to achieve paging vertically in asp.net C# in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to have paging in my asp.net gridview but here is the twist, I want the paging vertically. i.e when I hit page up and page down paging should occur vertically. Like when I do normal paging 1,2,3,4..... pages occur but I want no 1,2,3,4..pages, I want it to be done vertically when I hit page up and page down considering 10 records per page

Comment: i guess what you want is to show/hide one/two records per click(page up or page down)..you cant do it using any built-in functionality as far as i know...you will have to write your own custom paging subroutine

Comment: @thunderbird : I dont want to hide the previous 10 records, I want to just scroll 10 records downwards.

Comment: @zey : I want to scroll, down records. The post you suggested was to align the grid vertically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your gridview around a div and add `width` `height` and `overflow:scroll` to the div's style attribute.

```
<div style="width: 100%; height: 400px; overflow: scroll">
<ASP:GridView></ASP:GridView>
</div>
```

Also remove the `AllowPaging`attribute from the GridView. Adjust the width and the height of the div according to your needs.